# Angular: Uncaught SyntaxError when adding extra js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

**ADDED:**
*The error does not occur after downgrading local @angular/cli from 1.6.1 to 1.5.5.*

main.js file in my Angular /src/ directory:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('test'); //or any other js code   
});
```

Added in .angular-cli.json:

```
"scripts": [
  "main.js"
],
```

JQuery CDN is added in index.html.

With all this, the script is not working, and I get this in my console:

```
scripts.bundle.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

And here is what I get in the error source:
[image]

Angular version is 5.1.1.

Comment: Are you using a transpiler to convert ES6 to ES5 ? Some of the ES6 features might not have been implemented by the browser yet.

Comment: I'm not using any extra compile tools other than those of Angular.

Comment: Rename the file to `.ts`?

Comment: Seems like your code haven't been transpiled correctly. `import` is a very new keyword for browsers. In Chrome basic support for `import` was added quite recently (version 61). Check your webpack config so that it actually does the transpiling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens only if you name the script `main.js`.
Everything works fine with any other name.